# .net core routing, understand what application called with a generic route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

So what I have is a base controller that the following `[Route]` definition

```
[Route("{application}/api/[controller]")]
public class BaseController
{

}
```

All of my current controllers inherit from `BaseController`.

What I am trying to achieve is that two different application can call my controllers and my code to be aware of what 'application' is calling it.

Application 1 should be able to call `/Application1/Api/MyController`
Application 2 should be able to call `/Application2/Api/MyController`

and both requests should go to the same controller but my code should be aware of which application called it.

I thought about having some sort of Middleware and then work out the application from the `Request.Path`, and then store it in something like `HttpContext.Current.Items` but that doesn't seem like the correct way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "application"? You mean the client calling this over HTTP?

Comment: Yes, so each client can call using their client name for example google could call `/Google/Api/MyController/` and it would be the same controller as the other examples. It's just a string, it can be anything

Comment: Wouldn't you rather be passing this sort of info via an HTTP header than URL though? Or even use an API key of some sort that maps to an application?

Comment: I didn't really think about using a HTTP header. It's possible, would have just been easier for the client to do it via routing

Comment: I think that semantically it makes more sense though, if the URL is an identifier of the resource, then it should change based on the application calling it.

Comment: That was my initial thought in this, but I cannot seem to google the correct words to get an answer @DavidG :)

Comment: If you are fine with using a header, I can add an answer?

Comment: @DavidG You can add an answer, but ideally I want to see if anyone has any idea's reagarding this sort of dynamic route

Comment: I've added an answer that doesn't involve a dynamic route if nothing else it should give you ideas on how to proceed according to your requirements.

Comment: I've added a method that will let you put the application in the URL. One of those methods should hopefully get you sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal preference here would be to pass the value as an HTTP header rather than a route parameter, especially if you want it everywhere. It means you don't need a `Route` attribute and a different URL per application. Using a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`, there's a bunch of ways you can pass this detail into your action. For example:

```
public class ApplicationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Application", out var values))
        {
            // Method 1: This allows you to specify a parameter on your action
            context.ActionArguments.Add("application", values.First());

            // Method 2: This adds the value into the route data
            context.RouteData.Values.Add("Application", values.First());

            // Method 3: This will set a property on your controller
            if (context.Controller is BaseApplicationController baseController)
            {
                baseController.Application = values.First();
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And apply it to action methods or your controller:

```
[Application]
public class FooController : Controller
{
}
```

#### Method 1 Usage:

```
public IActionResult Index(string application)
{
    // do something with the parameter passed in
}
```

#### Method 2 Usage:

```
public IActionResult Index(string application)
{
    var application = (string)RouteData.Values["Application"];
}
```

#### Method 3 Usage:

First, create a base controller that contains the property:

```
public abstract class BaseApplicationController : Controller
{
    public string Application { get; set; }
}
```

Then make sure your controller inherits from it:

```
[Application]
public class FooController : BaseApplicationController
{
}
```

Now you can access the property on your controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string application)
{
    var application = this.Application;
}
```

#### Bonus Method 4:

As an aside, you could use this method to use the URL route value, using the base controller from method 3, modify the attribute to look like this:

```
public class ApplicationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Controller is BaseApplicationController baseController)
        {
            baseController.Application = (string)context.RouteData.Values["application"];
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Add a route attribute to your controller:

```
[Route("{application}/api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

And now you should have the property value on the controller set.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the route template into action and then each action would technically be aware of its caller context by your proposed convention:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet("{application}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string application)
    {
        if (application == "Application1")
        {
            ...Application1 called
        }
        if (application == "Application2")
        {
            ...Application2 called
        }
        ...        
    } 
}
```

Of course, this is your proposed convention and it is not enforced through some custom application authentication in any way so you will have to trust that your callers will correctly identify themselves through this convention.

Another approach, could be to have a base class variable and set that after inspecting the route.

```
[Route("{application}/api/[controller]")
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected string CallingApp { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
    {
        CallingApp  = ctx.RouteData.Values["application"];
        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with having it as part of the action method is that I would have to put it on every single one. Ideally i'd like to do it all in one place where anyone can add more API's without having to worry about the calling application

Comment: Can you not simply inspect the route in the base class constructor and set some string variable identifying caller context based on your convention?

Comment: How would you suggest you access that route variable in the base class constructor?

Comment: @JamieRees I've added you the example of how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, I originally thought it can be done in the constructor thus the readonly, but then realized the `HttpContext` won't be available at the point when constructor is invoked.